# I can't access to all my charts array keys

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-visualization

I'm working on PHP and JavaScript project using Google Charts,

I want to know how can I receive my **pageSpeed** and **pageSpeed2** elements.

PHP Code :

```
public function charts(){
    $this->charts['pageSpeed'] = [
        "columns" => [ // This key will store the definition of each column
                       ["key" => "string", "label" => "Browser"],
                       ["key" => "number", "label" => "Range"]
                     ],
        "rows" => [ // This looks more like a standardized model instead of random key-value pairs
                     ["string" => "JS",     "number" => 10],
                     ["string" => "Images", "number" => 30],
                     ["string" => "HTML",   "number" => 20],
                     ["string" => "CSS",    "number" => 30],
                     ["string" => "Other",  "number" => 10]
                   ]
                ];
    $this->charts['pageSpeed2'] = [
          "columns" => [ // This key will store the definition of each column
                         ["key" => "string", "label" => "Browser"],
                         ["key" => "number", "label" => "Range"]
                       ],
           "rows" => [ // This looks more like a standardized model instead of random key-value pairs
                         ["string" => "JS",     "number" => 10],
                         ["string" => "Images", "number" => 30],
                         ["string" => "HTML",   "number" => 20],
                         ["string" => "CSS",    "number" => 30],
                         ["string" => "Other",  "number" => 10]
                      ]
        ];
        echo json_encode($this->charts);
    }
```

my JavaScript/JSON Code :

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function(){
    if($('#charts').length){
        data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        url = window.location.href+'/charts';
        $.getJSON(url, params = null, function(feedback){
            $.each(feedback, function(keys, values){
                const tableData = feedback[keys];
                const columnKeys = tableData.columns.map(({ key, label }) => {
                    data.addColumn(key, label); // ("string", "Browser") for the first iteration, then ("number", "range")
                    //return key; // the "columnKeys" variable will then look like ["string", "number"]
                });
                data.addRows(tableData.rows.map((row) => columnKeys.map((key) => row[key])));

                var options = {"pieHole":0.4, "width":100, "height":100,'legend':'none', 'chartArea': {'width': '80%', 'height': '80%'}};
                // draw the chart
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(keys));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

How can i get all charts elements ?  right now i get only the pageSpeed key and not the pageSpeed2.

Comment: 1) You will not get more attention with more comments. 2) There is an error in your setup - your PHP editor uses tabs AND spaces within the same file. Set it to place 4 spaces instead of tab.

Comment: What is the value of $('#charts') when your function starts? Try using `console.log` or debugger.

Comment: is just div. just i check if the div exist